# Run an awk script on every file of a certain type in a directory

Tags: file, awk, directory

I have a directory with several hundred .log files in it, and I have a script to pull some info out of them and print it to an existing file. Running it on one file goes like

```
awk -f HLGcheck.sh 1-1-1.log >> outputs.txt
```

and this works fine.  I've looked around for several hours online and I can't seem to find a decent way to have it run on all .log files in the directory. Any help from people smarter than me would be appreciated.

Comment: You should maybe explain other ways you may have tried or found but which doesn't solve your issue

Comment: Using a `.sh` extension for an awk script is a little weird. And is the question here really just how to apply that to all the files? awk takes as many files as arguments as you give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash has for loop for this purpose

```
$ for f in *.log; do your_processing_here; done
```

you can refer to the file in processing as `$f`

Answer (score 1):

Some techniques:

If the awk script can only handle one file at a time, use a for loop as shown or

```
find . -name '*.log' -exec awk -f HLGcheck.sh '{}' \; >> outputs.txt
```

If the awk script can handle multiple files:

```
awk -f HLGcheck.sh *.log >> outputs.txt
```

```
find . -name '*.log' -exec awk -f HLGcheck.sh '{}' \+ >> outputs.txt
```